# How do I model/sculpt these scales on this video game model?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I'm trying to 3D print a video game model. The ripped model for the Dragon snake (Gobblegut) came with textures for the scales on the head and top half of the body. I tried displacing the mesh with the texture, but it didn't produce a good result. I thought it might be better to sculpt them from scratch, but I'm not sure how to model the scales. I attempted, but with no decent end result. I would appreciate it if someone could help me or give me some guidance. All that's needed is to model one of the scales. Once one is modeled, I can just copy and paste the scale-since the scales are the same and only vary in terms of scale and position.
I uploaded the Blender file if it helps.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Reference Model from Game]

[image: Blender- Ripped model]